# Move folders that have an apostophe in their name

Tags: mv

Hoping this is an easy one - can't quite get it to work.

I need to move all folders, and content (no sub folder) that have at least one apostrophe/quote in their name.

Any pointers?

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: @wjandrea As `mv` is one of the tags, I'd assume that they're using that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `'` using one of the usual escaping methods. BTW the glob pattern you will need is `*<glob_pattern_here>*/`,  the trailing `/` will make the shell to match only directory(ies).

- Using backslash, `\`:

  ```
  mv -t /destination/ *\'*/
  ```
- Using double quotes, `"`:

  ```
  mv -t /destination/ *"'"*/
  ```
- Using single quotes, `'`, this is actually same as using the backslashed one:

  ```
  mv -t /destination/ *''\'''*
  ```

You can do a `echo mv ...` first as a dry-run. Replace `/destination/` with your actual destination.

Also, you can try to use tab-completion if you feel to do it interactively.

Comment: `''\'''` is the same as `\'` since each `''` is a single-quoted null string.

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are simpler ways, but this should work in `sh` with no spaces in the file name

```
mv *[\"\']*
```